# image upload code is not working

Tags: laravel-4

i am new in laravel, i am facing a big problem and i can't solve this problem.
I am trying to upload image into my database and upload folder,but my code is not working,
Here is my controller code

```
public function store()
    {
        $rules=array(
              'gallery_name'=>'required',
              'image_title'=>'required',
              'image'=>'required'
        );
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $destinationPath = 'uploads/';
        // If the uploads fail due to file system, you can try doing public_path().'/uploads' 
        $filename = str_random(32) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        //$extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        //get all book information
        $galleryInfo = Input::all();
        //validate book information with the rules
          $validation=Validator::make($galleryInfo,$rules);
          $upload_success = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
          if($validation->passes())
          {
          //save new book information in the database 
          //and redirect to index page
              if ($upload_success) {
                    //save in the Band table database
                    Gallery::create($galleryInfo);
                            return Redirect::route('galleries.index')
                             ->withInput()
                             ->withErrors($validation)
                             ->with('message', 'Successfully created Gallery.');
                    }   
                     else {
                           return Redirect::route('galleries.create')
                           ->withInput()
                           ->withErrors($validation)
                           ->with('message', 'Image fields are incomplete.');
                    }
          }
          //show error message
          return Redirect::route('galleries.create')
               ->withInput()
               ->withErrors($validation)
               ->with('message', 'Some fields are incomplete.');
     }
```

please help me as soon.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: I am not getting any error message when uploading, Image moved into uploads folder correctly but image has not saved into database as .jpg or .png file name. It's saves by the name of my image location name in to database.

Comment: `Input::all()` will not deal with `Input::file()` regarding `Gallery::create()`. You must build the image file name before `$galleryInfo = Input::all()`, something like `Input::replace(['image' => $file->getClientOriginalName() . $file->getClientOriginalExtension())`

Comment: Provide inside the form an tag with 'files => true